# Получить сообщения из канала телеграм, которые были опубликованы сегодня

Tags: python, telethon

Как получить сообщения из телеграм канала, которые были опубликованы только сегодня? Не могу найти как передать в параметр `offset_date` текущую дату из модуля `datetime`. Если передаю самостоятельно написанную, то всё работает. Как автоматически передавать текующую дату?
И как получать текстовое сообщение вместе с медиа? Как отдельно получать знаю, а вот как всё вместе - не понимаю.

Работает корректно:

```
date = datetime(2023, 3, 29)

with TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    all_message = client.iter_messages('ссылка на тг канал', reverse=True, offset_date=date)
```

Не работает:

```
date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y.%m.%d')

with TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash) as client:
     all_message = client.iter_messages('ссылка на тг канал', reverse=True, offset_date=datetime.today())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте вместе посмотрим какие результаты будут выведены при выполнении вашего кода:

```
date = datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 29)
print(date, type(date))
```

> 2023-03-29 00:00:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'>

Клас `datetime` всё как положено, а что насчёт следующего примера?

```
date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
print(date, type(date))
```

> 2023.03.29 <class 'str'>

А вот это уже интересно. Почему мы видим класс `str`? Разбираемся. Попробуем выполнить код поочерёдно:

```
date = datetime.datetime.today()
print(date, type(date))
date = date.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
print(date, type(date))
```

Вывод:

```
2023-03-29 21:04:15.066619 <class 'datetime.datetime'>
2023.03.29 <class 'str'>
```

Значит функция `strftime` возвращает строку, на которую и ругается метод `iter_messages`. Решение: передавать экземпляр класса `datetime`. Как получить объект, использующий только дату без времени? Вот ответ:

```
date = datetime.datetime.today().date()
print(date, type(date))
```

> 2023-03-29 <class 'datetime.date'>

А ещё вы во втором примере передаёте объект класса `datetime` напрямую, в нём присутствует время и вероятно программа думает, что вы хотите получить посты конкретно за это время.

Comment: Всё очень подробно, благодарю за ответ!